# How to show up and down ratings next to prices? Material design app

Tags: android, material-design

I am designing android app in which user sees a listing of products with prices per unit and next to that need to show if its high price or low, please give me suggestions

Comment: Can you please give some more information about high/low level? Can you please provide some information on the use case .

Comment: yeah here what I want to show, Just let me know If its good to show like that?because I am new to material design [link](http://rohitbhosale.com/sample.png)

Comment: Can each card provide some more info on each item and the state(drop/increase).. The design is a bit unclear. Can give more details on it. May be that would better illustrate the state.

Comment: Up down arrows indicate change in rate compared to previous rates

Comment: Is it possible to provide by how much the rate is less or high when compared to the previous rate? Just saying it is high/less is not really a good design. May be a percentage value or the difference from previous rate will help the user gain some idea on what is it about. Showing relevant details will your design to be easily understood

Comment: yeah but as per requirement's approach just need to show it in a simple way. high or low ? If you have any idea to show it in material design or any  link that will help me out.Thanks

Comment: The design seems fine. 
The only concern is the amount of details. May be this will help :
http://cdn.techpp.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/cnbc.jpg
Just take a look at one item in the list. 
For making the design better, take a look at this:
https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/cards.html#cards-usage

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If you mean an indicator that tells you whether a price is high or low (compared to whatever reference group) and can do your own icon design/ selection, I would suggest something like the following:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDRgcB.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Okay Thats good wintvelt but I dont want to show it in such details. But Just to know user if its high or low. Just like stock market,
Here what I did [link](http://rohitbhosale.com/sample.png)

Comment: I see. The typical stock market symbols, the ones you also use, communicate that the price has gone up or done. So *compared to the price of the same item yesterday or in time*. If that's what you look for, then they are fine. What I thought you meant, and what I tried in my sketch, is to indicate whether the price is high or low *compared to prices of something else at the same time*, e.g competitors.

Comment: Thanks a lot. And you did great usability testing. That detailed info can also be useful

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3 characters for depiction of price
if price is high use ↑ character
if price is low use ↓ character
else if price is medium or ok use ↔ character